# Insert data in MySQL

Tags: asp.net

When I click on the button it should insert this data in database, but this doesn't happen. It just shows me a MsgBox and doesn't load the insert order.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim s As MySqlConnection = servconn("localhost", "root", "123")

        If s.State = ConnectionState.Connecting Then
            Using insert As MySqlCommand = s.CreateCommand
                insert.Connection = s
                insert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                insert.CommandText = "insert INTO exam.app (ID, UserName, Email, address) VALUES (NULL, '" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "')"
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(insert.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End If
    MsgBox("Inserted commpleted")
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be using executeNonQuery() rather than executeScalar(). An Insert statement does not return a value. And please use parameters instead of concatenating values together as a string - this leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Anyway have you debugged this? Is ConnectionState.Connecting true when you run the code?